# Difference between azure table storage and azure easy tables

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-table-storage

What is the difference (if any) between azure table storage and azure easy tables?

Comment: Azure Easy Tables is tied to an app service, backed by Sql Azure and is geard towards mobile apps. Azure Table Storage is more a general purpose NoSQL store.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there are totally different things.

Azure easy table which is used by the azure mobile app Node.js backend.

It is an easy way to CRUD the data to the sql database/azure storage account like EF.

We couldn't directly use it without binding the azure sql database and azure storage account.

Azure table storage is a service that stores structured NoSQL data in the cloud.

In my opinion, azure easy table is a tool to CRUD the data to the database.

Azure table storage is a database to store the  structured NoSQL data.